# Expand DIV auatomatically while having a table inside

Tags: html

I have a `table` inside a `DIV` , but the div height and width don't expanded automatically when the `Table`(:edited:) height and width are increased

Comment: div height and width don't expanded automatically when the DIV height and width are increased?????

Comment: could you please put your div and tables code here ?

Comment: @HemantMetalia div height and width don't expanded automatically when the table height and width are increased

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<td><div/></td>`

DIV's width should stretch the full width of the TD, minus TD's padding and DIV's margin (if any). However, DIV will never grow taller than its content, regardless of placement - you have to set its height. You should be able to set DIV's height to match TD's height, whether you use JS or whether that's rendered by server.

BTW, unless you're targeting some special height, the TD will grow in height as DIV grows, and DIV will start growing vertically as its content (assuming text) is longer than DIV's preset width (in  your case, TD's width).